# Domain redirection to a hashed URL

Tags: http, dns

I have a domain, lets say www.mycompany.com.

Is it possible to redirect www.mycompany.com to www.domain.com#mycompany instead through my domain provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, Your domain provider provides DNS servers that only resolve your domain names into IP addresses. Thereafter it is up to the clients/browsers to send the requested domain name or URL to one of the IP addresses. So usually your domain provider can not redirect your domain name to another URL. But you'd better check with your domain provider, they might provide HTTP servers to redirect the requests. Otherwise, you have to redirect it through your own HTTP  server.

Answer (score 1):

If you can put a web page at www.mycompany.com/index.html, put this in the content:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Page Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.domain.com#mycompany">
```

As Innerpeacer said, you can't really redirect a domain name to a hashed URL without going through a web page (or cgi) redirect.